# Open link in a new tab when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I want it to open in a new tab when the link in my hello button is clicked, how can I get it?

My Code:

```
 <Button
          href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6411367502435954294"
          type="primary"
          content="Play Store "
        />
```

All Code :

```
import styles from "./contact.module.scss";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import Social from "../Social/Social";

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.contactWrapper}>
      <div className={styles.socialWrapper}>
        <Social
          media="linkedin"
          href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nisaefendioglu/"
        />
        <Social media="github" href="https://github.com/nisaefendioglu" />
        <Social media="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/nisaefendioglu" />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        <Button
          href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6411367502435954294"
          type="primary"
          content="Play Store "
        />
        <Button
          href="mailto:nisaefendioglu0@gmail.com"
          type="secondary"
          content="Contact"
          icon={"paper-plane"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

SCSS

```
.buttonWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 20rem);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: var(--medium-space);
}
```

Button :

```
import styles from "./button.module.scss";

const Button = ({ content, icon, type, href }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <a
        className={`${styles.button} ${
          type === "primary" ? styles.primaryButton : styles.secondaryButton
        }`}
        href={href}
      >
        <i className={`fas fa-${ icon }`}></i>
        {content}
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: Is `Button` a custom component?, as the `href` should be applied to `a` not a `button`.

Comment: I shared all my code now @Mina

Comment: Still button component is not shared

Comment: .buttonWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 20rem);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: var(--medium-space);
}
 @PratikWadekar

Comment: @NisaEfendioglu, we need to see the code of the `Button` component not the SCSS, I see you import `import Button from "../Button/Button";`please output the code of that component.

Comment: sorry i added it now @Mina

Comment: import styles from "./button.module.scss";

const Button = ({ content, icon, type, href, target }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <a
        className={`${styles.button} ${
          type === "primary" ? styles.primaryButton : styles.secondaryButton
        }`}
        href={href} target={target}
      >
        <i className={`fas fa-${ icon }`}></i>
        {content}
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;

Comment: I can't add an answer as the question submitted as duplicated, you can use this code, and then set a `target="_blank" for the button, and it should work.

Comment: [many more examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=prop+target+how-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab-in-nextjs+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED CODE**

Add a `target="_blank"` attribute

```js
<Button
  target="_blank"
  href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6411367502435954294"
  type="primary"
  content="Play Store "
>
  {/*some code*/}
</Button>;

import styles from "./button.module.scss";

/* Include additional prop target in your button component */

const Button = ({ content, icon, type, href, target }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <a
        target={target}
        className={`${styles.button} ${
          type === "primary" ? styles.primaryButton : styles.secondaryButton
        }`}
        href={href}
      >
        <i className={`fas fa-${icon}`}></i>
        {content}
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this code too, but it opens on the same page.

Comment: Could you elaborate more as to how your Button component is built. Or are you using any component library ?

Comment: I shared all my code now

Comment: use inside <a></a> tag